# Show json result in MVC view table

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I am using MVC5 and get colors data in EF DbContext and show data in view by Javascript and Json in table tag. But link 'Details' in table not run Javascript function. Please hep me.

Color Model :

```
    public partial class ViewColors
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller :

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        EFModel db = new EFModel();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetColors()
        {
            var model = db.ViewColors.ToList();
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult ColorDetails(int ColorId)
        {
            var model = db.ViewColors.Find(ColorId);
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

View page :

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row">
    <table id="ColorList" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>R</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Group</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function displayData(response) {
            var strrow = "" ;

            if (response != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    strrow = "<tr>";
                    strrow += "<td>" + (i+1) + "</td>";
                    strrow += "<td>" + response[i].Name + "</td>";
                    strrow += "<td>" + response[i].GroupName + "</td>";
                    strrow += "<td>" + response[i].Comment + "</td>";
                    strrow += "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='ColorDetail' data-id='" + response[i].Id + "'>Details</a></td>";
                    strrow += "</tr>";
                    $("#ColorList").append(strrow);
                }
            }
        }

        $(function () {
            var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("GetColors", "Home")';
            $.getJSON(actionUrl, displayData);

            $(".ColorDetail").click(function () {
                alert("");
                debugger;
                var TeamDetailPostBackURL = '/Home/ColorDetails';
                var $buttonClicked = $(this);
                var ColorId = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
                var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { "ColorId": ColorId },
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        alert(data.Name + " " + data.GroupName);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: It looks like you are dynamically creating the row with the `ColorDetail` class on it.  As such the jQuery bind will not work because that row is not present when the page loads.  Instead, bind the event to the entire table like this `$('#ColorList').on('click', '.ColorDetail', function()...`